# PHP Google Analytics Reporting API. Retrieve data in chart

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I am using the Google Analytics Reporting API v4 in PHP.

I want to show the following data on a dashboard from another web page: list of the referrer urls and sessions coming from them at 30 and 120 days.

For that, I copied the code provided in the API documentation for web server applications (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-php) and made the pertinent changes to get the mentioned data.

My problem comes when I try to retrieve the data independently to use it to feed a chart.

Here is the Google Analytics Reporting API code, with modifications:

```
    // Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);


// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  // Call the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  $response = getReport($analytics); //see function below


} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */


 function getReport($analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "888888888"; //View ID replaced 

  // Create the DateRange objects.
  $monthly = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $monthly->setStartDate("30daysAgo");
  $monthly->setEndDate("today");

  $quarterly = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $quarterly->setStartDate("120daysAgo");
  $quarterly->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics objects.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
  $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

  // Create the Dimensions object.
  $fullReferrer = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
  $fullReferrer->setName("ga:fullReferrer");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges(array($monthly, $quarterly));
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
  $request->setDimensions(array($fullReferrer));

  //Call the batchGet method.
  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );

/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */

function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
    $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
    $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();
    for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
      $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
      $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
      $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
      for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
           $items_dim = array();
       foreach ($dimensions as $k =>$data){
            $items_dim[] = $data;
            }
            print_r($items_dim);  
      }

      for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
        $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
       for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
          $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];

            $items_val = array();           
            foreach ($values as $k =>$data){
            $items_val[] = $data;
          }
           print_r($items_val);
        }
      }
     }
  }
}

printResults($response->getReports());
   ?>
```

With the modifications I made, I managed to get a result  out of the

```
    printResults($response->getReports());
```

that looks like an array:

*Array ( [0] => **(direct)** ) Array ( [0] => 20 ) Array ( [0] => 168 ) Array ( [0] => **url1** ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => **url2** ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => **url3** ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 11 ) Array ( [0] => **url4** ) Array ( [0] => 0 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) ...*

The [0] references the sessions object. There are three items:

- url.
- sessions at 30 days.
- sessions at 120 days.

So the question is **how to retrieve the data from the result of the function so that it can be used independently to feed a chart**.

So far, I tried to store the function in a variable $results, so that then I can iterate through the array, but it is not working:

```
$results = printResults($response->getReports());
print ($results);
```

The above code prints one time the results.

```
$results = printResults($response->getReports());
//print ($results);
```

The above code prints one time the results too, so the work is done by the pintResults() function, not by the print().

I also tried to get stored in a variable $results when the function is defined (not working neither):

```
$results = function printResults($reports) {
  for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
    $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
    $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
    ...
```

Comment: print is the same as echo, it outputs strings, not arrays. try var_dump?

Comment: @delboy1978uk, 
    `$results = printResults($response->getReports());
     var_dump ($results);`
This returns NULL after printing the above said as a result of the printResults()

Comment: Have you considered embedding a Google Data Studio report instead? Much easier.

Comment: well yes, function printResults() doesn't actually return anything, does it?

Comment: @delboy1978uk, that is it

Comment: you have it working now?

Comment: how about $results = $response->getReports() ?

Comment: @ДмитроБулах,`$results = $response->getReports()` had no effect, as it is the function printResults() the one retrieving the results.